# Powershell assert pipeline returns not an array

Tags: powershell

Background:

I'm trying to filter a specific GIT branch from my local branches. Therefore I'm using `git branch --all`.

Powershell specific question:

I'm performing pipeline filtering via `Where-Object` and want to ensure that only one object and not an array is returned from the pipeline.

I've e.g. :

```
  $branch = Invoke-Expression "git branch --all" | % { $_.Trim('*').Trim() | ? { $_ -match "MySpecificBranchRegex" }
```

If I mess up my specific filter regex `$branch` might be an array and not a `string`.

Is there an elegant way to ensure only one string is returned. Possible solutions I don't like:

- Call `Select-Object -First 1` at the end of the pipeline
- Perform if '$arr.GetType().BaseType.Name -eq "Array"`

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `Select-Object -First 1` is the elegant solution imho, but you could turn it around by forcing it to always return an array:

```
$branches = @(Invoke-Expression "git branch --all" | % { $_.Trim('*').Trim() | ? { $_ -match "MySpecificBranchRegex" })

if ($branches.Count -ne 1)
{
    throw "Something went wrong..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = git branch --all | where { $_ -match 'MySpecificBranchRegex' } 
$result.count
```

I wouldn't be above using findstr (even with quotes) instead of where.  /i is case insensitive.

```
$result = git branch --all | findstr /i MySpecificBranchRegex
```